# How to use pressure correctly?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

So I am trying to learn how to make a cushion with this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4h097E4pRCw&t=461s
It should look like this...
[image: cushion]

But in my case setting the pressure to 10 doesn´t do anything. Why is that?
[image: my cushion]
here´s my file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hg3lh6tbpwbp2ed/couch3.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have set the pressure scale to 0.

try these settings and give collision modifier to your couch:

[image]

[image]

Comment: For simulations, you also should apply the scale to the object (Ctrl+A in *Object* mode)